# read_csv() doesn't work with StreamingBody object where python engine is required

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3

I am encountering a problem while using pandas `read_csv()`. Data is being read in from s3 as `StreamingBody` object and noticed it worked only when c engine parser is used. (per pandas [documentation][1], skipfooter only works with python engine parser)

Did anyone encounter a similar issue before? Or any advice to solve this problem? Thanks

The following is how I re-produced this issue.

```
import boto3
import s3fs
import pandas as pd

s3 = boto3.client("s3")
response = s3.get_object(Bucket="df-raw-869771", Key="csv/customer-01.csv")

pd.read_csv(response["Body"])

     customer_id|store_id|first_name|last_name|email|address_id|activebool|dw_insert_date|dw_update_date|active
0     9|2|MARGARET|MOORE|MARGARET.MOORE@sakilacustom...                                                        
1     13|2|KAREN|JACKSON|KAREN.JACKSON@sakilacustome...                                                        
2     17|1|DONNA|THOMPSON|DONNA.THOMPSON@sakilacusto...                                                        
3     21|1|MICHELLE|CLARK|MICHELLE.CLARK@sakilacusto...                                                        
4     25|1|DEBORAH|WALKER|DEBORAH.WALKER@sakilacusto...                                                        
...                                                 ...                                                        
1188  587|1|SERGIO|STANFIELD|SERGIO.STANFIELD@sakila...                                                        
1189  591|1|KENT|ARSENAULT|KENT.ARSENAULT@sakilacust...                                                        
1190  595|1|TERRENCE|GUNDERSON|TERRENCE.GUNDERSON@sa...                                                        
1191  599|2|AUSTIN|CINTRON|AUSTIN.CINTRON@sakilacust...                                                        
1192  4|2|BARBARA|JONES|BARBARA@sakilacustomer.org|8...                                                        

[1193 rows x 1 columns]
```

if passing in skipfooter argument

```
import boto3
import s3fs
import pandas as pd

s3 = boto3.client("s3")
response = s3.get_object(Bucket="df-raw-869771", Key="csv/customer-01.csv")

pd.read_csv(response["Body"], skipfooter=1)

__main__:1: ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support skipfooter; you can avoid this warning by specifying engine='python'.
    99  117  115  116  111  109  101  114   95  105  100  124  115.1  116.1  111.1  ...  114.28  103.11  124.112  53.6  55.4  124.113  65.51  99.26  116.33  105.31  118.13  101.35  124.114  49.70  51.21
0   45   49   49   45   50   48   49   57  124  124   49   10     53     55    124  ...      69      83       84   124    69       68     78     65      46      87      69      83       84     64    115
1   97  107  105  108   97   99  117  115  116  111  109  101    114     46    111  ...      76      68       73    78    69       46     80     69      82      75      73      78       83     64    115
2   97  107  105  108   97   99  117  115  116  111  109  101    114     46    111  ...      73      76       76    73    65       77     83     79      78      64     115      97      107    105    108
3   97   99  117  115  116  111  109  101  114   46  111  114    103    124     50  ...     114     103      124    50    55       48    124     65      99     116     105     118      101    124     49
4   51   45   49   49   45   50   48   49   57  124  124   49     10     50     54  ...     115      97      107   105   108       97     99    117     115     116     111     109      101    114     46
..  ..  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...    ...    ...    ...  ...     ...     ...      ...   ...   ...      ...    ...    ...     ...     ...     ...     ...      ...    ...    ...
84  99  116  105  118  101  124   49   51   45   49   49   45     50     48     49  ...      51      45       49    49    45       50     48     49      57     124     124      49       10     51     56
85  51  124   49  124   77   65   82   84   73   78  124   66     65     76     69  ...      51      53      124    50   124       82     73     67      75      89     124      83       72     69     76
86  66   89  124   82   73   67   75   89   46   83   72   69     76     66     89  ...      88      84       69    82   124       72     69     67      84      79      82      46       80     79     73
87  78   68   69   88   84   69   82   64  115   97  107  105    108     97     99  ...     103     124       53    52    53      124     65     99     116     105     118     101      124     49     51
88  45   49   49   45   50   48   49   57  124  124   49   10     53     52     51  ...     116     111      109   101   114       46    111    114     103     124      53      57       55    124     65

[89 rows x 1024 columns]
```

Comment: Can you try the `read_csv()` with the skipfooter argument on its own, or before the one without?

Comment: Thanks for your response. There is no issue at all if using a S3 URL with or without skipfooter... so it looks like something stopped working when both StreamBody object and python engine parse are used.

Comment: _There is no issue at all if using a S3 URL with or without skipfooter..._ Do you mean when using the one with skipfooter first, or on its own?

Comment: sorry i might not follow your question... the `skipfooter` argument cannot be used on its own....

Comment: Sorry if I explained it poorly. In the code you shared, you’re running `pandas.read_csv()` twice on the same input. What I meant is that you should test a short program which runs `pandas.read_csv()`only once, with the `skipfooter` argument.

Comment: thanks for the clarification. i've re-formatted the code block in the original post thanks

Comment: You managed to run it successfully? Problem solved, then?!

Comment: no... as can be seen the data is not parsed/converted correctly in the dataframe... everything is interpreted as `numbers`

Comment: Ah damn, alright, I'll try to take another look.